# Change default page folder on Asp net core Mvc 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

is there a way to change the default directory of ".cshtml" files from "Pages" folder to a custom one?

I tried with the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Test/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
 services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
 {
     options.RootDirectory = "/MyPages";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc().WithRazorPagesRoot("/MyPages");
}

For details folow the link
https://www.talkingdotnet.com/change-asp-net-core-razor-pages-default-directory-name/

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Employees/Index", "");
    });
}

For more follow the links
https://exceptionnotfound.net/setting-a-custom-default-page-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/
```